# how to make display to console text

Tags: console, c#

I am beginner at C# and I am trying like welcome message like as

```
 Console.WriteLine(" Enter Your Name:");
 Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
 Console.Write("first name:");
 string name = Console.ReadLine();
```

I need after entering the first name to clear the window and go for next output like:

```
 Console.Write("last name:");
 string lastname = Console.ReadLine();
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I think he is asking how to clear the window (console window?) after getting the first name. And then asking for the last name. So a clear window between the two blocks of code. It makes more sense now I've formatted the code blocks properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the console window with

```
Console.Clear()
```

If you put this in between your two blocks of code you should have what you need.

You can also make a blank line by doing

```
Console.Writeline();
```

Instead of

```
Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
```

Comment: In this case please consider to mark this answer as "solved"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this...

```
Console.WriteLine(" Enter Your Name:");

Console.WriteLine("first name:");
string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("last name:");
string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
```

Please feel free to use `Console.Clear()` to clear the console.

You may further print/see the values using

```
Consile.WriteLine("Your First Name is " + firstName + " and last name is " + lastName);
```